Is This Verilog Assignment Statement Legal? (Else assigment to itself)
I'm working on a Verilog project and have encountered a possible issue with an assignment statement. I wanted to check if the following code is legal in Verilog:
assign a = b ? v_in: a;

This code works in simulation, but I'm concerned about its legality. From my understanding, this might create a circular dependency, but I'm not certain if Verilog allows this in the context of an assign statement. Can someone please clarify if this is legal in Verilog? If not, what would be the recommended way to achieve the same logic without running into issues?

It's legal in the sense that it is not a syntax violation and can be synthesised.
The construct however relies on knowing the previous value of a to calculate the new value of a, but without any clocking. This means that it will infer a combinational latch.
If you absolutely need to use the construct, there is nothing specifically wrong with it, just be aware of the pitfalls of combinational latches in digital designs (there are other questions on this site that go into that).

If a clock is available and suitable for your design, the following does not infer a latch, but rather a clocked register:
always @ (posedge clock) begin
    a <= b ? v_in : a;
end

Again, that depends entirely on whether this is suitable for your design.
